# Creating a text template using a formula

Tags: process-builder, formula, lightning-textarea, textarea

I am attempting to get the following result in a text area in Salesforce using a Formula;

```
AccountName has opened a case requesting something. 
The case was opened by FirstName LastName, Please reach out to 
the customer at fake@email.com or by phone at 555-123-1234
```

I need the formula field to fill in the `AccountName`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Email` and `Phone Number` feilds from the record in such a way that the output is as above.

My current formula code is below;

```
[Case].Account.Name + ' has opened a case requesting something. The case was opened by ' + [Case].Contact.FirstName + ' ' + [Case].Contact.LastName ', Please reach out to the customer at ' + [Case].Contact.Email + ' or by phone at ' +[Case].Contact.Phone
```

When I attempt to save the Formula I receive the error `The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Extra has`

I have also tried the following two excerpts and receive the same error;

```
[Case].Account.Name + " has opened a case requesting something. The case was opened by " + [Case].Contact.FirstName + " " + [Case].Contact.LastName ", Please reach out to the customer at " + [Case].Contact.Email + " or by phone at " +[Case].Contact.Phone
```

and

```
[Case].Account.Name & " has opened a case requesting something. The case was opened by " & [Case].Contact.FirstName & " " & [Case].Contact.LastName ", Please reach out to the customer at " & [Case].Contact.Email & " or by phone at " & [Case].Contact.Phone
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, I thought one of these should have worked.

Any assistance is appreciated

Comment: What's wrong with your formulas?  do you get any errors? What part of them isn't working?  There's no point stating what you've tried if you don't also state why it didn't work.  Right now it's impossible to understand what your problem is, and therefore what question you're asking.  See also: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My apologies @NickCook, I thought that I had included the error message. The error message is `The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Extra has`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was staring me in the face the whole time. The correct format is

```
[Case].Account.Name & " has opened a case requesting something. The case was opened by " & [Case].Contact.FirstName & " " & [Case].Contact.LastName & ", Please reach out to the customer at " & [Case].Contact.Email & " or by phone at " & [Case].Contact.Phone
```

Issue Resolved

however I was missing a single `&` between last name and the next string